# Read-only Dependency Property updates but does not work on first use

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am trying to create a few WPF UserControls to include in a library to share with my team but there is something wrong with how Read-Only properties are working for me.

For this question I made a very simple user control with two DependencyProperties. One that is based on an `enum` and the other that performs an action based on the selected `enum`. The `enum` is being used to choose a style the button will use.

The application is a regular Wpf Application with a Wpf User Control Library as a reference. I have a suspicion that the Control Library *might* be contributing to the problem so I felt it was relevant to the example.

**Wpf Control Library1**

Dictionary1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1">
    <Style x:Key="SampleStyle-Font1">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Wingdings" />
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="30" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SampleStyle-Font2">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Elephant" />
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="30" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SampleStyle-Font3">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman" />
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="30" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}, Path=Command}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}, Path=ReadOnlyStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfControlLibrary1 {
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
        public enum StyleSelector {
            Style1,
            Style2,
            Style3
        }

        public static DependencyProperty SelectedStyleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedStyle", typeof(StyleSelector), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(ReadOnlyStyle_Changed));

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ReadOnlyStylePropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ReadOnlyStyle", typeof(Style),
                typeof(UserControl1), null);

        public UserControl1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public StyleSelector SelectedStyle {
            get => (StyleSelector)GetValue(SelectedStyleProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedStyleProperty, value);
        }

        public Style ReadOnlyStyle => (Style)GetValue(ReadOnlyStylePropertyKey.DependencyProperty);

        private static void ReadOnlyStyle_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (!(d is UserControl1 userControl1)) {
                return;
            }

            Style style;
            switch (userControl1.SelectedStyle) {
                case StyleSelector.Style1:
                    style = (Style)userControl1.FindResource("SampleStyle-Font1");
                    break;
                case StyleSelector.Style2:
                    style = (Style)userControl1.FindResource("SampleStyle-Font2");
                    break;
                case StyleSelector.Style3:
                    style = (Style)userControl1.FindResource("SampleStyle-Font3");
                    break;
                default:
                    style = (Style)userControl1.FindResource("SampleStyle-Font1");
                    break;
            }

            userControl1.SetValue(ReadOnlyStylePropertyKey, style);
        }
    }
}
```

**Wpf Application**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ReadOnlyDependencyPropertiesWithUserControls.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReadOnlyDependencyPropertiesWithUserControls"
        xmlns:wpfControlLibrary1="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Example" Height="200" Width="400">
    <StackPanel>
        <wpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1 SelectedStyle="Style1" Content="This is the first control"></wpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1>
        <wpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1 SelectedStyle="Style2" Content="This is the second control"></wpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1>
        <wpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1 SelectedStyle="Style3" Content="This is the third control"></wpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The output below shows that the first control does **not** show a `Style`. If I run the application, switch it to Style2 using the Live editor and then back to Style1, the WingDings font does take over, but on a fresh run it does not. It definitely seems like a Dependency Property issue, but as far as I can tell I have the setup correct, especially since the other two controls seem to work.

[image: The first control should use the WingDings font, but does not]

Comment: According to the dependency property naming conventions, the identifier fields for the `ReadOnlyStyle` property shoud be named `ReadOnlyStylePropertyKey`, not `ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey`.

Comment: Besides that, it might by a lot simpler to directly assign the Label Style from a Style resource in a Setter inside a DataTrigger in the UserControl's ControlTemplate in XAML. No need for the ReadOnlyStyle property.

Comment: @Clemens You caught a copy-paste fail from another experiment. I made the correction. Thank you! That was just a naming issue so it obviously still doesn't work. I am certainly not married to the ReadOnlyProperty. It was the first thing I found that actually (almost) worked for what I am trying to accomplish. I will investigate DataTriggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

The reason why it does not work is because you assign the `ReadOnlyStyle` property value inside of `SelectedStyle` property changed handler. Since `SelectedStyle` is of type `StyleSelector` which is an `enum`, and you don't explicitly assign default value for this property, it will have default value of `default(StyleSelector)` assigned by the framework, which happens to be `StyleSelector.Style1`. And even if you explicitly assign that value to this property on your first control, the value doesn't really change, ergo the handler is not invoked, ergo `ReadOnlyStyle` remains `null`, ergo you get what you get (a `Label` with default style).

#### Solution

In order to remedy that, you should assign initial value of `ReadOnlyStyle`. But since the styles are kept in a resource dictionary, you cannot do that in the constructor. A good point to assign the initial value would be this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);
    var style = (Style)userControl1.FindResource("SampleStyle-Font1");
    SetValue(ReadOnlyStylePropertyKey, style);
}
```

#### Better solution

"The *WPF* way" of achieving your goal would be to use triggers. So first of all you could remove unnecessary code from your control:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public enum StyleSelector
    {
        Style1,
        Style2,
        Style3
    }

    public static DependencyProperty SelectedStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedStyle", typeof(StyleSelector), typeof(UserControl1));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public StyleSelector SelectedStyle
    {
        get => (StyleSelector)GetValue(SelectedStyleProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedStyleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then modify your temlpate:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}, Path=Command}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label x:Name="PART_Label" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="local:UserControl1.SelectedStyle" Value="Style1">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Label" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SampleStyle-Font1}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="local:UserControl1.SelectedStyle" Value="Style2">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Label" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SampleStyle-Font2}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="local:UserControl1.SelectedStyle" Value="Style3">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Label" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SampleStyle-Font3}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Two important things here are:

1. The `Label` needs to have `x:Name` so it can be referenced in `Setter.TargetName`
2. `Trigger.Property` value needs to be fully qualified, because `ControlTemplate` does not have `TargetType` set.

Comment: Your "WPF way" solution is exactly what I was looking for. I knew the way I was building it wasn't the best way but it has been the only solution that was actually semi-working. I actually had a solution being built using triggers but my implementation was incorrect. You filled in the gaps so thank you for that.